# Does screen sharing via Firefox allow another website to control your Mac, or just your browser?

Tags: macos, security, big-sur, screen-sharing, firefox

Recently I was requested to share my screen to take an online exam. The security implications of this concerned me.

Firefox says:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/screenshare-safety

[image]

This to me sounds like in the worst case, the site you are sharing with can manipulate your web browser.

But to allow Firefox to screen share, requires one to go to system settings and authorise Firefox to share the screen. This made me wonder what Firefox, and the end website I am sharing the screen with can do, so I visited this website:

https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh14066/mac

This is where my question comes up, as I was unable to find an answer on apples web page:

- If I share my entire screen with a website via Firefox, does that mean they can control my Mac, restart it, launch applications, browse folders, open files etc ?
- Or, are they only able to see what is on screen and manipulate my web browser?
- The reason I am asking specifically, is because while Firefox's page mentions controlling the browser window, Apple's screen sharing website talks about the ability to open applications, browser files etc. The confusion is because I'm not sure if Apple's website refers only to screen sharing from Mac to Mac, or allowing applications (such as Firefox) on a Mac to Screen share opens up the same risks
- Or does it mean that we are placing our trust in Firefox, and by providing Firefox with the ability to screen share, Firefox and open other applications, browser files, control Mac etc, and by transitivity a website that Firefox is screensharing with can control your Mac?

Comment: macOS Screen Sharing is different from Firefox screen sharing.

Comment: @nohillside Thanks. Does that mean that all Firefox screen sharing can do is manipulate my web browser and display my screen, but not launch applications or access files ?

Comment: I won't vouch for that, and actually hope somebody has an answer explaining what Firefox screen sharing can and can not do. Anyway, if unsure it's usually a safe option to create a dedicated user account on your Mac just for the single purpose of using Firefox screen sharing.

Comment: @nohillside Makes sense. The Mozilla website talks only about the risks to data stored in the browser. While Apple's website seems to refer to Mac to Mac screen sharing. But I am unable to find a link which talks about the impact of allowing any application on a Mac permission for screen sharing.

Comment: It's technically not the same thing. FF screen sharing is implemented in the browser, Mac Screen Sharing is part of the OS. So FF screen sharing is (assuming no bugs) limited to accessing the things FF can access (which already might be a lot).

Comment: @nohillside Ah! Now I get it, I think I mixed up screen sharing with screen recording. Firefox calls it screen sharing, but is uses MacOS' screen recording feature, not screen sharing, so I guess obviously Firefox can only display the screen and manipulate the browser with those permissions. Guess we figured it out.